# Bootstrap table not cropping for tablet devices

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, html-table, responsive

I'm using Twitter-Bootstrap for a table. The table works fine for bigger screens and for mobile. For tablet it doesn't work. What I want is the following:

[image]

The image above is how it is on mobile. I want this too for tablet, but when I select tablet resolution on Chrome I get this:

[image]

It's not responsive. How can I fix this?

Code:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Breedte</th>
            <th>Hoogte</th>
            <th>Doekkleur</th>
            <th>Omkastingkleur</th>
            <th>Bedieningtype</th>
            <th>Bedieningkant</th>
            <th>Uitvoer</th>
            <th>Geleider links</th>
            <th>Geleider rechts</th>
            <th>Opvulling</th>
            <th>Onderlat-type</th>
            <th>Extra</th>
            <th>Prijs</th>
            <th>Actie</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($result as $offer) { ?>
          <tr>
            <td><?php echo $offer['width'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $offer['height'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $offer['clothingcolor'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $offer['housingcolor'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $offer['controltype'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $offer['controlside'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $offer['output'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $offer['conductorleft'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $offer['conductorright'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $offer['stuffing'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $offer['underlattype'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $offer['extra'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $offer['price'] ?></td>
            <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-link" name="getValue" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".editProduct<?php echo $offer['id']; ?>" data-id="<?php echo $offer['id']; ?>"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true" style="color: red;"></i></a></td>
          </tr>
        <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
      </table>
</div>
```